# How to add a user to a role?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

There is existing code in my application that does this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Customer Account Admin"))
                    //
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mi = radmenu1.Items.FindItemByText("Admin");
                        radmenu1.Items.Remove(mi);
                    }
```

What puts the user in that role
We are NOT using the old Role Manager. We are using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and this doesn't seem to do it:

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();


    if (manager.AddToRole(manager.FindByName(UserName.Text).Id, "Customer Account Admin").Succeeded)
    {
       c.logActivity("Register.aspx.cs", "REG_USER_ROLE", "Setting user to Admin role succeeded");
                                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IsInRole**.

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager 
{
   get 
   {
      if (_userManager == null) 
      {
         _userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
             .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
      }
      return _userManager;
   }
}

bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), 
   "Customer Account Admin");
```

Comment: Doesn't that just check that he is that role? I want to add him to the role.

Comment: I don't need that. I don't need to find out if he is in the role. I need to add him to that role.

Comment: You original said **How to get user in a role?** Anyhow, **AddToRole** should work. Have you try `var roleResult = await UserManager.AddUserToRolesAsync(user.Id, RoleNames);`? The **AddUserToRolesAsync** helper method comes with [Microsoft ASP.NET Identity Samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples)